# Adding values of multiple data frames per a specific variable

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

I am trying to compute the following: µ+bi+bv, where µ = the average of all scores, bi = average of a specific row, and bv = average of a specific column.

The matrix is a 15x31 matrix. If I were to try to find the value of cell (1,1), for instance, how would I go about this. I would want to add the averages of row one with column one, then add µ.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you add data using `dput` and show expected output for the same?

Comment: I've added how to handle the NA values to my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `mat` is your matrix I guess this should give you what you want :

```
mat2 <- mat
mat2[] <- colMeans(mat)[col(mat)] +  mean(mat) + rowMeans(mat)[row(mat)]
```

Add `na.rm = TRUE` in `rowMeans` and `mean` if you have `NA` values.

Using this data :

```
mat <- matrix(1:15, ncol = 3)
mat
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    6   11
#[2,]    2    7   12
#[3,]    3    8   13
#[4,]    4    9   14
#[5,]    5   10   15

mean(mat)
#[1] 8

rowMeans(mat)
#[1]  6  7  8  9 10

colMeans(mat)
#[1]  3  8 13

mat2[] <- colMeans(mat)[col(mat)] +  mean(mat) + rowMeans(mat)[row(mat)]
mat2

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]   17   22   27
#[2,]   18   23   28
#[3,]   19   24   29
#[4,]   20   25   30
#[5,]   21   26   31
```

---

We already have calculated all the values in `mat2`, to replace only `NA` values we can subset those values and replace them with their corresponding mean.

```
mat2[] <- colMeans(mat, na.rm = TRUE)[col(mat)] +  
             mean(mat, na.rm = TRUE) + rowMeans(mat, na.rm = TRUE)[row(mat)]

mat[is.na(mat)] <- mat2[is.na(mat)]
```

Comment: That helps. I am trying to basically predict missing values through this process, so how would I go about targeting only the "NA" values with this formula?

Comment: @JamieWarren Updated the answer to replace only `NA` values.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `outer()` on the row and column means and add the overall mean.

```
outer(rowMeans(mat), colMeans(mat), `+`) + mean(mat)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the `matrix()` function and `ncol()` and `nrow()`

```
# Using the data Ronak Shah provided
mat <- matrix(1:15, ncol = 3)

# Solution
mat2 <- 
  # matrix mean
  mean(mat) +
  # column means
  matrix(rep(colMeans(mat), nrow(mat)), nrow = nrow(mat), byrow = TRUE) + 
  # row means
  matrix(rep(rowMeans(mat), ncol(mat)), nrow = nrow(mat), byrow = FALSE)
```

This returns

```
> mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    6   11
[2,]    2    7   12
[3,]    3    8   13
[4,]    4    9   14
[5,]    5   10   15
> mat2
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   17   22   27
[2,]   18   23   28
[3,]   19   24   29
[4,]   20   25   30
[5,]   21   26   31
```

`mat2[1,1]` for example = `mean(mat) + colMeans(mat)[1] + rowMeans(mat)[1]` = 8 + 3 + 6 = 17

---

If you want to use it to replace NAs in the original matrix just add `na.rm = TRUE` to all your mean functions, then reference the matrices with `is.na()` and sub assign

```
mat <- matrix(1:15, ncol = 3)
mat[1,2] <- mat[4,3] <- NA

# Solution
mat2 <- 
  # matrix mean
  mean(mat, na.rm = TRUE) +
  # column means
  matrix(rep(colMeans(mat, na.rm = TRUE), nrow(mat)), nrow = nrow(mat), byrow = TRUE) + 
  # row means
  matrix(rep(rowMeans(mat, na.rm = TRUE), ncol(mat)), nrow = nrow(mat), byrow = FALSE)

# Replace the NAs
mat[is.na(mat)] <- mat2[is.na(mat)]
```

Giving

```
     [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
[1,]    1 22.19231 11.00000
[2,]    2  7.00000 12.00000
[3,]    3  8.00000 13.00000
[4,]    4  9.00000 26.94231
[5,]    5 10.00000 15.00000
```